# Extend mobile view in Kendo UI Mobile?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, prototype, prototypal-inheritance, kendo-mobile

It doesn't seem possible to extend the view for mobile. I would like to do so because I can predefine some options and behavior. I have create a [sample here illustrating the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/basememara/67RZN/), which gives me an error of:

`Your kendo mobile application element does not contain any direct child elements with data-role="view" attribute set. Make sure that you instantiate the mobile application using the correct container.`

JavaScript:

```
kendo.mobile.ui.plugin(kendo.mobile.ui.View.extend({
    init: function (element, options) {
        kendo.mobile.ui.View.fn.init.call(this, element, options);
    },
    options: {
        name: 'ViewCustom'
    }
}));

$(function () {
    new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body);
});
```

HTML:

```
<section data-role="layout" data-id="default">
    <header data-role="header">
        <div data-role="navbar">My App</div>
    </header>
    <footer data-role="footer">
        <div data-role="tabstrip">
            <a href="#home" data-icon="home">Home</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
</section>

<div id="home" data-role="viewcustom" data-layout="default">
    Welcome to the home page!
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/basememara/67RZN/

---

Kendo support simply said it's not supported - the mobile application does not recognize the descendants and does not initialize them upon start. This is a huge extensibility roadblock for mobile, so I've been poking around the source code to see where this is hard coded and I think the change will be somewhere in `ViewEngine` in [kendo.mobile.view](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/blob/master/src/kendo.mobile.view.js), possibly in `_hideViews`. I also see some hard coded views in [kendo.mobile.pane](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/blob/master/src/kendo.mobile.pane.js). So I think this will be a big hack of the source code to get it working.

My question is there a way to extend the view without creating a new class, such as using prototype to extend kendo.mobile.view? Any help, experience, or insight will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of relying on Kendo to find the initial view to display, which will search specifically for `data-role="view"` you can instead programmatically tell it the initial view:

```
new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body, {
    initial: "home"
});
```

I [updated your example](http://jsfiddle.net/67RZN/3/) (and clicking the "Home" button also navigates to a second view just to make sure that worked as well).